# Помогите настроить gitconfig / git clone директорию

Tags: git, настройка, git-config, clone

Хотел бы в `~/.gitconfig` добавить строку, которая определила бы конкретную директорию по умолчанию  для клонирования. Нaпример:

```
/home/user_name/Git_s
```

PS в google ответа не нашел.

Comment: вопрос не понятен. Попробуй изложить его ясней и без ошибок

Comment: В чем у вас проблема при вызове `git clone git://some.repo.url/project.git`?

Answer (score 5):

вероятно, подразумевается, такой сценарий:

чтобы при выполнении команды

```
$ git clone <url>
```

вне зависимости от текущего каталога хранилище создавалось бы в каталоге `/home/user_name/Git_s/имя/.git`.

а рабочая копия хранилища — в каталоге `/home/user_name/Git_s/имя` (где `имя` — стандартно генерируемое из `url` имя для каталога: `repo` для `/path/to/repo.git` и `foo` для `host.xz:foo/.git`).

---

реализовать подобное поведение можно, например, с помощью «псевдонима» (*alias*). что-нибудь вроде:

```
$ git config --global alias.cl '! mkdir -p /home/user_name/Git_s && cd /home/user_name/Git_s && git clone'
```

здесь псевдонимом будет `cl`, и, выполняя впоследствии такую, например, команду:

```
$ git cl user@host:group/myrepo.git
```

вне зависимости от того, какой каталог в этот момент будет текущим, хранилище вы получите в каталоге `/home/user_name/Git_s/myrepo/.git`, а рабочую копию — в каталоге `/home/user_name/Git_s/myrepo`.

---

если в этот момент каталог `/home/user_name/Git_s/repo` уже существует **и** не пуст, то данная команда, понятно, завершится ошибкой. в таком случае можно, как и для «обычной» команды `clone`, добавить желаемое имя под-каталога:

```
$ git cl user@host:group/myrepo.git another-name
```

тогда хранилище будет создано в каталоге `/home/user_name/Git_s/another-name/.git`, а рабочая копия — в `/home/user_name/Git_s/another-name`

---

приведённая выше команда (`git config --global ...`) добавит в глобальном конфигурационном файле (обычно `~/.gitconfig`) в секции `[alias]` строку:

```
cl = ! mkdir -p /home/user_name/Git_s && cd /home/user_name/Git_s && git clone
```

что можно сделать и самому (при желании).